# MYSQL count(*) returning 1 agaisnt an empty table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am running this query in Codeigniter

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT count(*) FROM `friends` WHERE uid=$logged_id AND who=$id")
```

however the table friends is empty, their is nothing inside of it

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
 return $query->num_rows();
}
```

the query above returns 1, when clearly it should return 0

modifying the query too

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM `friends` WHERE uid=$logged_id AND who=$id")
```

gives me 0, as expected

is their something special about count(*) that I am not aware off?

Answer (score 7):

You're retrieving the *number of rows* from your query where you should be actually retrieving the query *result.* For an empty table, this is what `count(*)` would give you:

```
count(*)
--------
       0 <- 1 row, containing the value 0.
```

It (along with `max()` or `sum()` or any aggregating function really) will give you *one* row of data regardless of how many rows are actually in the table (though a different `group by` may change that). That row will contain the count as **data** (which would be zero for an empty table).

The reason it works when you select `id` is because that's getting the rows out of the table rather than counting them and giving you one row regardless.

Answer (score 5):

Your query `SELECT count(*)` returns one row with the count of rows in it. You'll always get a row count of 1 from this.

You need to retrieve the row and look at the count that it contains.